# Automatic down scroll during boot and sometimes in apps

Tags: linux, keyboard, touchpad, scrolling, solus

I am facing some weird issues since a few days, all of which seem to be arising due to a single problem.

Once the boot menu pops up, the selection immediately jumps to the last entry (which in my case is 'Reboot into Firmware interface'). I need to go up and select a kernel explicitly, whatever be the default setting. During the boot, I see some `^[[6~` characters on the screen. Similarly, when I open some apps (say Geary), sometimes the list of messages automatically gets scrolled down to the last entry and tries to jump ahead of the last entry (beeping). If I press a button (any button), the movement stops. So basically I guess the system is registering down key-presses (or probably touchpad scroll) automatically during boot and in sometimes in some apps. During boot it is always reproducible, but not in the apps. Does the control character `^[[6~` point towards anything?

Any suggestions on diagnosing/resolving the problem?

*p.s.* I am using Solus Budgie (clr-boot-manager) on a Lenovo Z50-70 laptop.

Comment: It looks like a hardware failure.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way I could figure out whether it's due to the touchpad or the keyboard? Even if I disable the touchpad from the OS, it will still be recognizable during boot right?

Comment: Grub doesn't use any pointing device at all.

Comment: Do you know what does the character-sequence `^[[6~` correspond to?

Comment: Just in case this is useful. I don't have grub. Solus uses `clr-boot-manager` on UEFI.

Comment: `^[[6~` is PgDn.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and @IporSircer; indeed PgDn was the culprit. I have asked for a keyboard replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If it's due to some faulty key getting pressed automatically, you can detect it as follows

1. Install `xev`, can be installed using package manager in all major Linux distributions.
2. Open a terminal (**not as `sudo`**) and type `xev`
3. `xev` shows every key press and mouse events. Keep the system undisturbed and wait for sometime, and troubleshoot the faulty key

Also it may be a `kernel` issue or Display issue. To figure out please try booting using a `Ubuntu` live disk and observe the issue is present or not. If the issue is resolved then it's probably some kernel and driver issue, otherwise it may be a display issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found that this was a faulty-key problem (PgDn).